# Android Studio: Layout hierarchy problems

Tags: java, android, xml, image, android-layout

I have a horizontalScrollView containing 1 image that is used as the background. This image can be scrolled left to right. I would like to place other imageviews on to the background image but not have them scroll with it. At the moment if I place another imageview on top of this, when I scroll the image comes as well.

The scroll view at far left:

[image]

The scroll view at far right:

[image]

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_rear_gunner"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:focusable="true"
tools:context="com.example.mr_br.ibcc_bomber_command.rear_gunner">


<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" app:srcCompat="@drawable/background_scroll_2"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"

/>

</HorizontalScrollView>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/item_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:focusable="true"
    tools:context="com.example.mr_br.ibcc_bomber_command.rear_gunner">

</RelativeLayout>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:srcCompat="@drawable/placeholder_bomber"
    android:id="@+id/enemy" android:layout_centerVertical="true"


/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Very new to using layouts in android. Hope I made my problem clear if not I do apologize and will try to clarify if asked. I know this could have something to do with what layouts I am using and the child and parents of them layouts but like I said new to this.

Comment: Sorry, can't get your issue. If the enemy is the airplane, it doesn't scroll with the background as per your image.
What is the expected result?

Comment: the airplane is the enemy yes. The result I want is when I say scroll to the right the airplane remains at its starting location on the left and goes off screen and if I say scroll back to the left it goes back onto the screen.

Comment: Maybe creating a view bigger than the screen size would solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HorizontalSCrollView can have only one child, but that child could be another layout, so you can add as many ImageView you want.

```
  <HorizontalScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="3000dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="#a30"
          />
      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="30dp"
          android:layout_height="30dp"
          android:background="#aa0"
          />
    </RelativeLayout>
  </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: That was very helpful thank you. I believe this to solve my issue on some level but I also believe its the logic i am thinking about the problem as well. But thank you very much for the help and this was helpful